# Comparing information/finding duplicates on two spreadsheets

Tags: excel, database, excel-formula, countif

I have two spreadsheets: one has a list of people currently working in my company and the other has a list of people that have ever worked at our company, including current and past employees.

I somehow want to connect these two spreadsheets so that the result gives me a list of people that do not work there anymore.

Would this be possible?

Comment: you can achieve this by formulas, but if you are looking for a tool, try ASAP Utility, a free addin for Excel. It will automate this.

Comment: No I don't think you can ask excel here as that's not related to programming directly

Comment: Oh! Looks like I made a mistake. The framing of question and my newly found skills in excel made me think that :)

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your list of people currently working in your company is in ColumnA of sheet `Current` and your list of people that have ever worked at your company, including current and past employees is in ColumnA of sheet `AllTime`, in a new sheet enter:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Current!A:A,AllTime!A1)>0,"",AllTime!A1)
```

and copy down to suit.

Provided the range is enough this should automatically update for additions and deletions in either of `Current` or `AllTime`.

There should be gaps in the output (where employees are current) and these gaps could be closed up with a formula but depending on the size of your list you may prefer not to close up. If you want a compact list at a point in time simply filter your third sheet to exclude blanks in the relevant column, select and then paste into a range without hidden rows.

Comment: Thank you so much!!